# In my case scroll is not happening or may be happening too fast

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll

```
{ action: 'press',options: {
  x: 1044, y: 2341, ms:700
},},
{action:'wait',options: { ms:900},},
{ action: 'moveTo',options: { x: 1044, y: 952, ms:900 },},
{action:'wait',options: { ms:1000},},
{action:'release'},
```

this is the code that I'm using
please suggest the workaround or what I'm doing wrong

```
{ action: 'press',options: {
  x: 1044, y: 2341, ms:700
},},
{action:'wait',options: { ms:900},},
{ action: 'moveTo',options: { x: 1044, y: 952, ms:900 },},
{action:'wait',options: { ms:1000},},
{action:'release'},
```

expecting the sroll functionality to work but its not working on react native app

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you explain what's wrong and what's not working? Can you do a [mre] with your react code about this json model? Are the `,` at the end not creating issue?